# unity input controls

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, input

so im going through the roll a ball tutorial for unity and ive gotten though setting up all the controls to allow my ball character to move around the space ive built. but the tutorial says nothing about setting up what buttons trigger the movement. i found out where the input settings are for each axis and ive tried messing around in there but no matter what i do nothing seems to make my ball start moving around its little platform. does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: What specific settings did you try? The defaults should work just fine if you're using a QWERTY keyboard, arrow keys, or a standard gamepad. Did you remember to click inside the play window first to ensure it had input focus?

Comment: thanks i just tried clicking inside the play window and that worked im so excited to be able to continue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the game player window inside the Unity editor, and built game executables, will receive and process input only when they have focus.

To ensure your game has focus, click inside its window.

Unity gives the game window focus automatically when you hit the "Play" button to test your game, but if you accidentally click outside of it or go modifying stuff in the inspector, it can lose focus and make your input seem to stop. Clicking back in fixes it.